# How does a cathode half reaction work with different metal electrode and electrolyte

Tags: electrochemistry

If you had a galvanic cell with the cathode half cell using silver as its electrode and Copper Sulfate as its electrode, will the copper (s) coat the silver electrode?

Comment: Do you mean copper sulfate as an electrolyte ans copper metal as an anode? If yes, then the answer to your question is yes, as silver is more noble metal than copper.

Comment: Sorry I meant silver as the cathode half cell electrode with the electrolyte of the cathode half cell being copper sulfate. When the electrons are given from the anode reaction, will the copper ions in the cathode electrolyte coat the silver cathode electrode?

Comment: The electrolyte for the two half cells has to be copper sulfate. The copper  metal must be the anode. In this case copper will coat the silver cathode.  We call copper the sacrificial anode.